# Issue in android internet radio app

Tags: android, internet-radio

i add this code in my radioapp main activity class. its worked

```
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    // Toast.makeText(appContext, "BAck", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);
    alert.setTitle(string.app_name);
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    alert.setMessage("Are You Sure You Want To Quit?");

    alert.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                          radioServiceBinder.onDestroy();
                         finish();
                }



            });

    alert.setNegativeButton("NO",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               }
            });
    alert.show();
    return true;
}

return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

But i check my app its show in running apps after exits and show message **This service is run by its app.RadioService stop will be fail** and after few minutes my radio auto played i dont know how solve this. :(

Comment: `onDestroy` does not destroy a service. it is called by the system to notify you that the service is being destroyed. use stopSelf or stopService to ask the service to stop.

Answer (score 0):

You should never be calling onDestroy directly on a service.  You should instead call stopService, which will cause all the lifecycle functions to be called in the right order.

Comment: i create a another file for radioservice RadioService.java and in this file add this code `public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
  mediaPlayer.reset();
  isPrepared = false;
  sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_DESTROYED));
 }`

Comment: If that's an actual service (which I'm guessing from the name), then calling onDestroy directly will NOT kill the service and will screw up the Android framework.  Call stopService instead.

Comment: ok tell me this code is correct `radioServiceBinder.stop();
                            radioServiceBinder.onDestroy();
                            finish();`

Comment: No.  Use the Context function stopService.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29